# Xcode debugger -- inspect a deeply nested object

Tags: xcode, debugging

I have a recursive-descent tree object.  I want to be able to set a breakpoint and inspect it in the Xcode debugger.  Inspecting the top level works just fine.  But after I go down a level or so, the debugger says the values of the ivars are out of scope.  Is there any way I can keep this from happening?

EDIT:

In response to a comment --

The ivar is an object of class Expression.  The nesting mostly comes from the body ivar, which is typically an NSMutableArray of expression objects.  So you might have a structure like this:

-Expression
---body (2 expressions)
-----0 Expression
-------body (1 expression)
----------0 Expression
------------body [empty]
-----1 Expression
-------body [empty]

There is also a head ivar, which is an object of class Token, which in turn has some string ivars, does not nest.

The way I use the debugger -- I set a breakpoint in a method inside the Expression object.  I then click on the disclosure triangle for arguments, then for self, then for the body ivar, then for expressions within the body ivar, and so on.  But eventually the debugger stops telling me the values of things.

Comment: Starting a bounty for an answer to this.  The best answer would be one that does not involve writing any code.  But even an answer that involves extra code to bring the ivars into scope would have value if there is a way I can write the code once, then be able to inspect any object tree of my class, without specifying in advance exactly where in the tree I will want to go at runtime.

Comment: Could you specify the ivars type? And how are you using the debugger? With mouse clicks or commands typed in gdb's console?

Comment: This thread may be of interest to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427871/xcode-3-2-debug-seeing-whats-in-an-array

Comment: That is interesting, thanks.  But even after putting "{(int)[$VAR count]} objects {(NSString *)[(NSArray *)$VAR description]}:s" into the summary field, I can still only inspect the contents of the top-level body.  I tried it with and without the quotes.

Comment: Would a console-related solution be acceptable for you? You could implement a custom `description` method for your class that recursively invokes `description` on the objects contained and constructs a string this manner. This way you could get the entire tree by invoking `description` on the root instance, similar to what the debugger would do (see the linked thread for how to do that on the debugger console). You might not be able to ask for sub-trees, but you could inspect the tree at runtime.

Comment: That's basically what I'm doing now.  It's workable.  I'd rather be able to directly inspect the ivars, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend adding this to your `Expression` class. Then you can `po [expression explode]` in the debugger to print the tree of an expression. A prerequisite is a proper `-description` method for your `Expression`class that prints out the rest of the ivars.

```
- (void) explodeAtLevel:(int)aLevel {
    NSMutableString* out = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

    for (int i = 0;  i < aLevel; i++) [out appendString:@"-"];

    [out appendString:self.description];
    printf("%s\n", [out UTF8String]);
    [out release];

    for (id *subitem in body)
      if ([subitem isMemberOfClass:[Expression class]])
        [((Expression*)subitem) explodeAtLevel:(aLevel + 1)];
}


- (void) explode {
  [self explodeAtLevel:0];
}
```

Comment: This appears to be the best I can do.  Though isKindOfClass is much better than isMemberOfClass.  One question -- when I run that method in the debugger, I often get the message "Value can't be converted to integer."  When I run the same method from code in the program, I don't get that message.  Can you explain what is going on?

Comment: `isKindOfClass` is indeed better if you're having subclasses of your base class. As for the debugger message, I suggest trying to comment out `[out appendString:self.description];`. If the problem goes away, it's something in your `-description` method.