# Dereferencing pointer to array when debugging in XCode 4.2

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm using XCode to follow along in an intro to programming C++ class. No grade involved, I'm simply living vicariously through the eyes of others. Now that we've reached the subject of pointers I'm having trouble keeping track of where I am. If I pass a pointer to a dynamic array into a function how can I dereference that pointer to see what's actually being held in the various positions of the array. My code is compiling, but a couple of the functions are returning garbage. A clear indication that something isn't point to the right place.

Thanks in advance!
--John

Answer (score -1):

It's likely that some code will be needed to further understand your problem, but from what I understood, here is what you need.

```
#include <iostream>
void f(int *array){
    std::cout<<array[5];
}
int main(){
    int* array = new int[10];
    array[5] = 20;
    f(array);
    return 0;
}
```

This will print "20".

Comment: That's what I want the code to do, what I'm asking about specifically has to do with the Xcode IDE. When I've inserted a break point, say at the beginning of the function f() when the debugger gets there all I see is the value of the first element in the array, something like *array = 5 (for example, assuming the first element of this array is indeed 5). How do I get the Xcode implementation of gdb to spill the guts of say array[4] or array[3]?

Comment: @John seems that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1427871/xcode-3-2-debug-seeing-whats-in-an-array is what you want.

Comment: Your search foo is strong! That seems to be exactly what I need. I'll look it over in depth tomorrow -- it's late here :(